# why following shell script function failing?

Tags: shell

```
_exec()
{
    CMD="$1"
    echo "Executing command: $CMD"
    EXEC_OUT=`$CMD`
    EXEC_RET=$?
}
_exec  "hostname|cut  -d\".\" -f1 "
SHORT_NAME=$EXEC_OUT
if [ $EXEC_RET -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Unable to determine shortname of server"
else
    echo $EXEC_OUT
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What is the error you are getting? How do you call the function? What have you tried already?

Comment: these are my debug results?

Comment: + _exec 'hostname|cut -d"." -f1'
+ CMD='hostname|cut -d"." -f1'
+ echo 'Executing command: hostname|cut -d"." -f1'
Executing command: hostname|cut -d"." -f1
++ 'hostname|cut' '-d"."' -f1
te.sh: line 5: hostname|cut: command not found
+ EXEC_OUT=
+ EXEC_RET=127
+ SHORT_NAME=
+ '[' 127 -ne 0 ']'
+ echo 'Unable to determine shortname of server'
Unable to determine shortname of serve

Comment: when the function puts $CMD to execute it puts 'hostname|cut' '-d"."' -f1 te.sh

Comment: I suggest you post these answers in your original question and read in the help section about formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to evaluate your cmd on your exec function.

```
EXEC_OUT=`eval $CMD`
```

Not sure about why though. I think it's because there are several commands in a single variable. Maybe someone more experimented can confirm this.

See eval [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/eval.html).